# What is 'local variable referenced before assignment'

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I am trying to solve a problem at checkio(house password)
..my code is as follow

```
def checkio(data):
    if len(data)>9:
        for i in data:
            if str.isdigit(i)==True:
                global counternumber
                counternumber=counternumber+1
            if str.isupper(i)==True:
                global counterupper
                counterupper=counterupper+1
            if str.islower(i)==True:
                global counterlower
                counterlower=counterlower+1
    if (counternumber>1 & counterupper>1 & counterlower>1):
        return True
else:
    return  False
```

for this function while trying to implement the folowing error pops up

NameError: global name 'counterupper' is not defined

before declaring as global variables the error would pop up

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counterupper' referenced before assignment,
```

what do these errors mean and how to solve them??

please explain clearly as I am new to programming..

Comment: You didn't really search, did you ? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=local+variable+referenced+before+assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write in short:

```
def checkio(data):
    return (len(data) > 9 and
        any(ch.isdigit() for ch in data) and
        any(ch.isupper() for ch in data) and
        any(ch.islower() for ch in data))
```